# Self duplicate background script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, background

This is a background script test.

When run it launch two processes and I don't understand why.

One stop after sleep 20. And other forgets.

```
#!/bin/bash

back(){
    n=0
    while [ 1 ]
    do      
        echo $n
        n=$(($n+1))
        sleep 5
    done
}

back &
sleep 20
exit
```

command "ps -a" in call:

```
PID    TTY      TIME      CMD
8964   pts/2    00:00:00  backgroundtest
8965   pts/2    00:00:00  backgroundtest
8966   pts/2    00:00:00  sleep
8982   pts/2    00:00:00  sleep
```

after sleep 20:

```
PID    TTY      TIME      CMD
8965   pts/2    00:00:00  backgroundtest
9268   pts/2    00:00:00  sleep
```

then run forever...

why?

Answer (score 0):

`while [ 1 ]` is an infinite loop. `[ 1 ]` is always true.

So `back &` is an infinite loop, started in background (`&`), then execution continues with `sleep 20`, which *does* end after 20 seconds, leaving you with two processes for 20 seconds (`&` starts a new process in background), then the infinite one after that.